# TeX Capacity exceeded...\lst@framelr ->\copy \lst@framebox

Tags: errors, xetex

Below is an error that I receive after trying to include a Matlab file.

`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=3000000].
\lst@framelr ->\copy \lst@framebox`

The code given below compiles with the error.  Here is the rub, if XeLaTeX decides to somehow run the code for a second time on its own, I do not get the error.  Even if I delete the PDF and SYNC file, I will get the error. I am able to compile the code without errors using LauTeX.  I only get the errors when using XeLaTeX.

I just wanted to know if the cause of this error can be deciphered from this post and how to possibly fix it?  Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, oneside, fleqn, openright]{report}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.6cm, bindingoffset=1.5cm, headheight=30pt, bottom=3cm, top={120pt+10mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,mleftright}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\definecolor{myblueii}{RGB}{63,200,244}
\definecolor{myblueiii}{RGB}{199,234,253}
\newcommand*{\maincolor}{myblue}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstlinebgrd}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[font={color=mybluei},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={bf}]{caption}

%======================================================================================
%   FONTS
%======================================================================================
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{avant}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\listofdataname}{List of Data}
\newcommand{\listofresultname}{List of Results}
\newcommand{\listofmatlabname}{List of Matlab Code}
\usepackage[explicit,calcwidth]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fourier}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc,arrows,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing,pgfplots.groupplots, matrix}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, title/.append style={align =center}}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={remember picture}}
\pagestyle{plain}

\newcounter{result}
\newcounter{matlab}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm, bm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

\usepackage[sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,autolang=hyphen,hyperref=true,backref=true,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../References/chapter1.bib}% BibTeX

\usepackage{bookmark}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}

\newcommand\ph\mlplaceholder
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\phOpDelim@mlpr{$\langle$}
\renewcommand\phClDelim@mlpr{$\rangle$}
\makeatother

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,listings}

\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=result,list inside=result,number within=chapter,list type=result]{\inputresult}[3][]{%listing options={style=mystyleresults},%
    list text = {#2},
    enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,colbacktitle = myblueii,
    %opacitybacktitle=0,%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\bfseries\strut Result~\theresult~--~continued},%
    listing only,listing options={xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,style=mystyleresults},after upper={\centering\strut{\bfseries Result~\theresult:}~#2},%
    listing file={#3},#1}
\newtcbinputlisting[use counter=matlab,list inside=matlab,number within=chapter,list type=matlab]{\inputmatlab}[3][]{%
    list text = {#2},
    enhanced,noparskip,breakable,colback=myblueiii,opacitybacktitle=.8,%
    fonttitle=\bfseries,before upper={\hspace*{-1em}{#3}},%
    title after break={\centering\footnotesize\itshape\strut Matlab Code~\thematlab~--~continued},%
    listing only,listing options={frame=none,xleftmargin=-1mm,#1,numbersep=18pt,style=Matlab-editor,basicstyle=\mlttfamily\scriptsize},
    after upper={\centering\strut {\bfseries Matlab Code~\thematlab:}~#2},
    frame hidden,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,
    overlay={\draw[gray!80,line width=1mm] ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.north west) -- ([xshift=-0.5pt]frame.south west);},
    %
    listing file={#3},#1}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyleresults}{
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{black},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{black},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=b,
    keepspaces=true,
    numbers=none,
    numbersep=5pt,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=6
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ttll@result}{-1000}
\newcommand{\ttll@matlab}{-1000}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{sample.m}
%MDL_PUMA560 Create model of Puma 560 manipulator
%
% MDL_PUMA560 is a script that creates the workspace variable p560 which
% describes the kinematic and dynamic characteristics of a Unimation Puma
% 560 manipulator using standard DH conventions.
%
% Also define the workspace vectors:
%   qz         zero joint angle configuration
%   qr         vertical 'READY' configuration
%   qstretch   arm is stretched out in the X direction
%   qn         arm is at a nominal non-singular configuration
%
% Notes::
% - SI units are used.
% - The model includes armature inertia and gear ratios.
%
% Reference::
% - "A search for consensus among model parameters reported for the PUMA 560 robot",
%   P. Corke and B. Armstrong-Helouvry,
%   Proc. IEEE Int. Conf. Robotics and Automation, (San Diego),
%   pp. 1608-1613, May 1994.
%
% See also SerialRevolute, mdl_puma560akb, mdl_stanford.

% MODEL: Unimation, Puma560, dynamics, 6DOF, standard_DH

%
% Notes:
%    - the value of m1 is given as 0 here.  Armstrong found no value for it
% and it does not appear in the equation for tau1 after the substituion
% is made to inertia about link frame rather than COG frame.
% updated:
% 2/8/95  changed D3 to 150.05mm which is closer to data from Lee, AKB86 and Tarn
%  fixed errors in COG for links 2 and 3
% 29/1/91 to agree with data from Armstrong etal.  Due to their use
%  of modified D&H params, some of the offsets Ai, Di are
%  offset, and for links 3-5 swap Y and Z axes.
% 14/2/91 to use Paul's value of link twist (alpha) to be consistant
%  with ARCL.  This is the -ve of Lee's values, which means the
%  zero angle position is a righty for Paul, and lefty for Lee.
%  Note that gravity load torque is the motor torque necessary
%  to keep the joint static, and is thus -ve of the gravity
%  caused torque.
%
% 8/95 fix bugs in COG data for Puma 560. This led to signficant errors in
%  inertia of joint 1.
% $Log: not supported by cvs2svn $
% Revision 1.4  2008/04/27 11:36:54  cor134
% Add nominal (non singular) pose qn


% Copyright (C) 1993-2017, by Peter I. Corke
%
% This file is part of The Robotics Toolbox for MATLAB (RTB).
%
% RTB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
% it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
% the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
% (at your option) any later version.
%
% RTB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
% but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
% MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
% GNU Lesser General Public License for more details.
%
% You should have received a copy of the GNU Leser General Public License
% along with RTB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
%
% http://www.petercorke.com

clear L
deg = pi/180;

% joint angle limits from
% A combined optimization method for solving the inverse kinematics problem...
% Wang & Chen
% IEEE Trans. RA 7(4) 1991 pp 489-
L(1) = Revolute('d', 0, 'a', 0, 'alpha', pi/2, ...
    'I', [0, 0.35, 0, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [0, 0, 0], ...
    'm', 0, ...
    'Jm', 200e-6, ...
    'G', -62.6111, ...
    'B', 1.48e-3, ...
    'Tc', [0.395 -0.435], ...
    'qlim', [-160 160]*deg );

L(2) = Revolute('d', 0, 'a', (0.4318+0.0005), 'alpha', 0, ...
    'I', [0.13, 0.524, 0.539, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [-0.3638, 0.006, 0.2275], ...
    'm', 17.4, ...
    'Jm', 200e-6, ...
    'G', 107.815, ...
    'B', .817e-3, ...
    'Tc', [0.126 -0.071], ...
    'qlim', [-45 225]*deg );

L(3) = Revolute('d', 0.15005, 'a', 0.0203, 'alpha', -pi/2,  ...
    'I', [0.066, 0.086, 0.0125, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [-0.0203, -0.0141, 0.070], ...
    'm', 4.8, ...
    'Jm', 200e-6, ...
    'G', -53.7063, ...
    'B', 1.38e-3, ...
    'Tc', [0.132, -0.105], ...
    'qlim', [-225 45]*deg );

L(4) = Revolute('d', 0.4318, 'a', 0, 'alpha', pi/2,  ...
    'I', [1.8e-3, 1.3e-3, 1.8e-3, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [0, 0.019, 0], ...
    'm', 0.82, ...
    'Jm', 33e-6, ...
    'G', 76.0364, ...
    'B', 71.2e-6, ...
    'Tc', [11.2e-3, -16.9e-3], ...
    'qlim', [-110 170]*deg);

L(5) = Revolute('d', 0, 'a', 0, 'alpha', -pi/2,  ...
    'I', [0.3e-3, 0.4e-3, 0.3e-3, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [0, 0, 0], ...
    'm', 0.34, ...
    'Jm', 33e-6, ...
    'G', 71.923, ...
    'B', 82.6e-6, ...
    'Tc', [9.26e-3, -14.5e-3], ...
    'qlim', [-100 100]*deg );


L(6) = Revolute('d', 0, 'a', 0, 'alpha', 0,  ...
    'I', [0.15e-3, 0.15e-3, 0.04e-3, 0, 0, 0], ...
    'r', [0, 0, 0.032], ...
    'm', 0.09, ...
    'Jm', 33e-6, ...
    'G', 76.686, ...
    'B', 36.7e-6, ...
    'Tc', [3.96e-3, -10.5e-3], ...
    'qlim', [-266 266]*deg );

p560a = SerialLink(L, 'name', 'Puma 560_a', ...
    'manufacturer', 'Unimation', 'ikine', 'puma', 'comment', 'viscous friction; params of 8/95');


p560a.model3d = 'UNIMATE/puma560';

%
% some useful poses
%
qz = [0 0 0 0 0 0]; % zero angles, L shaped pose
qr = [0 pi/2 -pi/2 0 0 0]; % ready pose, arm up
qs = [0 0 -pi/2 0 0 0];
qn=[0 pi/4 pi 0 pi/4  0];


clear L

\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\lstlistoflistings

\tcblistof[\chapter*]{matlab}{\listofmatlabname}
\tcblistof[\chapter*]{result}{\listofresultname}

\chapter{New Code}

\inputresult[label=restult:testresult1]{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}
\inputresult[label=restult:testresult1]{Expansion Algorithm}{sample.m}
\inputmatlab[label=thisisatestlabel10]{This is a very long name for the Code that I hope will work}{sample.m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the code that you posted doesn't cause the error, but you think it might cause the error with a longer document?  My guess is that the error is something within your document, not the length of it.  Could you try commenting out various `input`s and narrow down what's causing the error?

Comment: I've answered some of your questions, but your setup is very complex and I think you're putting too much efforts into eye-candy

Comment: without a test file not really possible to say if it's an error or not, you may have something with a bug so it uses unbounded amounts of memory or perhaps you just have a page with a lot if data and have simply run out of memory, you can increase main memory in `texmf.cnf` or use lualatex which uses dynamic allocation, but if you are in an infinite loop using arbitrary amounts of memory that won't help

Comment: @Teepeemm, I edited the post with code that causes the problem on my machine.  Please see updated post.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's not really an error your data is just too big, you need to specify bigger main mem for xetex, I got no errors but main mem usage was (just!) more than 3000000

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 65499 strings out of 493010
 1498515 string characters out of 6135495
 3011727 words of memory out of 5000000
 68392 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 629301 words of font info for 93 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,6n,128p,10373b,3284s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

Output written on pp726.pdf (10 pages).
```

You could probably load less packages (are you really using all of those in one document?

my texmf.cnf says

```
main_memory = 5000000 % words of inimemory available; also applies to inimf&mp
```

I thought that was the default for texlive, put perhaps I have increased it previously, I don't recall.  In any case you should be able to increase this number in your local texmf.cnf.

You can use

```
kpsewhich --all texmf.cnf
```

to see where that is.

Comment: Hello,  I tried your command at the Windows prompt but nothing happens.   I do not see where I can view the main_memory.  Can you direct me as to where I can get and then modify that information?  Thanks!

Comment: @Joe you hadn't said you were on windows, kpsewhich and the texmf.cnf file would be the same on windows texlive but if you have miktex it will be some equivalent setting in its configuration options, but I don't have miktex so can't give the details.